# Безопасное хранение ключей шифрования

Tags: java, android, безопасность

Существует ли в Java под android возможность хранить ключи шифрования безопасным образом, например защищенными паролем?

Раньше генерировал так:

```
final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(4096, new SecureRandom());
final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: а почему вы не может использовать этот код сейчас?

Comment: потому что мне нужно паролем защитить ключи

Comment: не правильно поняли. Нужно защищённое хранилище для ключей

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения зашифрованных ключей можно использовать [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). Ключ генерируется как обычно и помещается в хранилище.

```
final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(4096, new SecureRandom());
final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

SecretKey mySecretKey = key.getPrivate();
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("password");
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
    new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey);
keyStore.setEntry("MySecretKey", skEntry, protParam);
```